# problem with web browser

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I'm try to retrieve the contents of a texblock and put it in a  webbrower in order to avoid html content :

desc1 is a variable recovered OnNavigatedTo method when navigating between pages
the problem is that I generate this exception:
invalid ioerationexception
plz help
thank you

```
   var desc1 = NavigationContext.QueryString["desc"] as String;
   BrowserControl.NavigateToString("<html>"+desc1+"</html>");
```

Comment: Could you please provide us with some more information?
- An example of the content of the desc1 variable
- Why do you want to wrap it in a BrowserControl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it this works for me,

try and set a variable to your desc1, then go back to the xaml editor and create a loaded event handler for your page which will do the webbrowser task

```
string s;

    public MessAbout()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var desc1 = "text" as string;
        s = desc1;

    }

    private void loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.NavigateToString("<html>" + s + "</html>"); 
    }
```